# jQuery UI Draggable scroll issue

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

The problem with my function is that when I scroll down, the clone of the element I want to drag is positioned under my mouse pointer, this only happens in FF, IE and Safari, Chrome works like it should.

I already tried all answers on this question :

[jQuery draggable shows helper in wrong place after page scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791886/jquery-draggable-shows-helper-in-wrong-place-when-scrolled-down-page)

But without succes,

I use jQuery 1.8.3 & jQuery UI 1.10.3

hopefully anyone has any idea on how to fix this.

You can view a live version of my webpage here : http://www.solar-sell.eu/uw-pv-systeem/?gezin=true

The people are the draggable elements and the house is the drop area.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem is a jQuery UI bug - http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9315