# JqueryUI Drag: Cursor not at the same position as draggable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using the latest version of JQuery and JQuery UI to understand drag and drop features. I am facing a minor problem - mostly due to mouse drag.

> As you can see that I am creating stacks with some items in it.
>
> Now if these stacks are just inside body - I mean div.allstacks is in
>   body there is no problem. But as soon as I put all these stacks inside
>   a div#left-panel, the problem of cursor losing focus starts.
>
> This means now when I drag an item, after horizontal scroll - My mouse
>   cursor is not at the same position of draggable note.

Now here is the problem:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

**JSFiddle Link [Working without div#left-panel]:
http://jsfiddle.net/deveshz/YvmFf/**

**JSFiddle Link [NOT Working with div#left-panel]
http://jsfiddle.net/deveshz/YvmFf/1/**

---

Here is the code.

Javascript:

```
var zindex = 10; 
$(".item").draggable({
    containment: "body",
    scroll: true,
    revert: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).css("border", "none");
        return !event;
   },
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).css("z-index", zindex++);
        $(this).css("border", "2px solid #333");
    }
});

 $(".stack_items").droppable({
    hoverClass: "over",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $("<li class='item'></li>").html(ui.draggable.html()).appendTo(this);
        $(ui.draggable).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Devesh, it's a (5 year old) bug in jQuery UI, all possible fixes are available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791886/jquery-draggable-shows-helper-in-wrong-place-when-scrolled-down-page.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a thorough look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I tried out and read through the link given by @konrad, I found that its a bug in Jquery UI  - even in the latest version of it. The problem got solved as soon as I started using Jquery UI 1.9.2 version

here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/deveshz/YvmFf/2/

with same code:

```
var zindex = 10; 
$(".item").draggable({
    containment: "body",
    scroll: true,
    revert: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).css("border", "none");
        return !event;
   },
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).css("z-index", zindex++);
        $(this).css("border", "2px solid #333");
    }
});

 $(".stack_items").droppable({
    hoverClass: "over",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $("<li class='item'></li>").html(ui.draggable.html()).appendTo(this);
        $(ui.draggable).remove();
    }
});
```

It uses Jquery version 1.9.2 from http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: did u find the what was the source of your issue and how this solution solved your problem? can you give some brief explanation