# Jquery drag and drop not working properly in Chrome Browser when code placed in Joomla Article

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Placed a jquery drag and drop example in joomla article. It's working properly with firefox browser but not working in chrome browser. In chrome, actually drag and drop is working but problem is that buttons are not visible on dragging.

Here's link to my example - http://joomla3.guru99.com/lesson-3.html

Here's My fiddle - `*http://jsfiddle.net/dB3B6/*`

Here's the screenshot of my problem
for chrome - http://screencast.com/t/eFqhUUoYY
for firefox - http://screencast.com/t/vZPvto3x

please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrading version of jQuery-Ui to 1.10.2 works for me... thanx @chainsawsalad

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in the version of jQuery UI you're using (1.10.3): http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9315.

I suggest downgrading to 1.10.2 if you can afford to, as this issue is not reproducible there (according to the ticket).

The other options are waiting for 1.11.0 to be released, which is version the ticket is assigned to, or hack together a solution to the offset problem via events, which is illustrated in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5795852/3100850