# use draggable divs with jqueryUI sortable and bootstrap (cursor take distance from divs in col-xs-6)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I want to make a draggable divs with `jquery UI` and `bootstrap` like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2mj2up6/) but when I want to drag third divs at the end it takes distance from cursor.

```
$(function() {
    $( ".columns" ).sortable({
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not getting your problem, Please justify it more.

Comment: when I want to drag blue box it gets space from mouse arrow how can I remove this space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use cursorAt: { left: Value , top: Value} for set your mouse location

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I have solved it by adding this options

```
$("#sortableList").sortable({
  appendTo: "body",
  helper: "clone",
  scroll: false,
  cursorAt: {left: 5, top: 5},
  start: function(event, ui) {
    if(! $.browser.chrome) ui.position.top -= $(window).scrollTop();
  },
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    if(! $.browser.chrome) ui.position.top -= $(window).scrollTop();
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

It seems some versions of jquery-ui have a bug in draggable functionality.
And sortable functionality depends on draggable.

For more details look this [jQuery draggable shows helper in wrong place after page scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791886/jquery-draggable-shows-helper-in-wrong-place-after-page-scrolled)

Answer (score 0):

This is updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h2mj2up6/1/

You have given class column to sortable div, and column class is acutally not having any meaning. So i have just updated that class to row-fluid which is perfect to work with responsiveness and you will not have problem of spacing while dragging those divs

```js
$(function() {
    $( ".row-fluid" ).sortable({
         
    });
 
   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:red;">
first first first first first first first first
 </div>
<div class="col-xs-6" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;right:0px;left:0px;">


   <div class="row-fluid">
   
    <div class=" col-xs-6" style='background-color:green;'>
              second</br> second
             second</br> second
              second</br> second

    </div>
   
    <div class=" col-xs-6" style='background-color:blue;'>
     third<br> 
           third<br>
           third<br> 
           third<br>
           third<br> 
           third<br>
    </div>
   
  </div>
  
 
 
 
</div>
```